# TRadioButton dropped on TListBoxItem behaves erratically when scrolled

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tlistbox

I am trying to implement a Firemonkey TListbox that has a number of TListBoxItems. On one of the TListBoxItems I have placed a number of TRadioButtons by simply dropping them on the TListBoxItem at design time. When the application is run the visual appearance of the buttons is erratic when the TListBoxItem is scrolled off the screen and back on.

Another TListBox question here at StackOverflow makes the point that a TListBox does not host any item other than a TListBoxItem. That being said, there seems to be no such restriction that I can find about a TListBoxItem. I have routinely placed TEdit, TLabel and TComboBox components in this manner without difficulty.

To duplicate the condition start a new Firemonkey desktop application; drop a TListBox on the form and set it to alClient; populate the TListBox with a number of TListBoxItems; set the heights of the TListBoxItems or Form so that when run, you are able to scroll the TListBox; drop three TRadioButtons on the topmost TListBoxItem; set the GroupName for all the TRadioButtons to the same name; run the application; select a TRadioButton so that it appears selected; scroll the TListBox so that the TListBoxItem containing the buttons scrolls off the form; scroll back; continue selecting different TRadioButtons and scrolling until anomalies are observed.

Questions: First and probably most important, am I permitted to simply drop components on a TListBoxItem at design time? Has my previous success with this technique been simply accidental?

Second and also of importance for an application I'm working on, if this is NOT a viable approach to my UI, can anyone suggest better approaches?

TIA

I entered a Report at Embarcadero's Quality Central and after a few exchanges with Tomohiro-san along with Marcus Adams suggestion that the problem is related to scrolling came up with the following:

Tracking through the various cases mentioned it appears that there are a number of other cases that are related to this one because of the use of scrolling. When an item is scrolled off the screen and then scrolled back the system apparently reapplies the styles to the items being returned to visibility. At least, in the few cases I have traced that seems to be the case. It is on this reapplication of style and rendering that the problem seems to occur. In my own examples I have added a button that displays the IsChecked property for the controls and the rendering does not reflect the property correctly in all cases, suggesting that it is the style/rendering that is causing the issues.

The related issues I was able to find are:

QC 120593
QC 117381
QC 119638
QC 117658

I'm waiting for a resolution.

Comment: Since my original posting I have tried the same exercise except by using TTreeView and TTreeViewItem. The same anomalies occur.

Comment: this problem occurs with any `ScrollBox`-based component. So you can simply add `TVerticalScrollBox` component on form, then add some radiobuttons and then try to scroll. I've faced with it a week ago, so i'm upvoting your question.
ps: as I know there is no restrictions about placing other components on `TListboxItem`s at desing time. it should work fine. But you should keep in mind that, if you need few list items, wich look the same, then you can use custom styles for `listboxitem`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I found no solution, but as a work-around, I ended up just replacing the radio buttons with check boxes and adding code so that they behaved in a similar manner to Radio buttons. E.g., only allowing one of a group of check boxes to be selected...